# Comparar strings com for e if no python(exercício)

Tags: python, lógica

Olá, eu estou fazendo um simples exercício no Python para aprender melhor a linguagem. O exercício consiste em imprimir valor true quando uma string de tamanho qualquer contém uma letra de outra string. exemplo string 1 abc e string 2 bca saida: true. Mas quando a string não contém nenhuma letra da segunda o valor deve ser false. Meu código não consegue detectar a letra de forma correta caso a letra da segunda string esteja numa posição diferente exemplo: aa cbaa false, mas deveria ser true. Segue aqui o código:
acredito que so estou conseguinto comparar a posição zero.

```
#definfo tamanho da lista
prescricao = list(range(26)) #nome do medicamento prescrito
estoque = list(range(26))# nome do medicamento no estoque
#ciclo for ´para usuário digitar dados
for n in prescricao: # ler dados de prescrição
  prescricao[n] = input("") #entrada de dados
  if prescricao[n] == '':  #comando "break" caso usuário apertar enter
        break
for e in estoque:  # ler dados de estoque
  estoque[e] =  input("") #entrada de dados
  if estoque[e] == '':  #comando "break" caso usuário apertar enter
        break
est = len(estoque)  
print(est)
for i in range(est):
  if estoque[i] == prescricao[i]:
    print(True)
  else: 
    print(False)
  exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está certo em dizer que só está conseguindo comparar a posição zero dos dois strings. Se olharmos a estrutura desse `for` loop:

```
for i in range(est):
  if estoque[i] == prescricao[i]:
    print(True)
  else: 
    print(False)
  exit()
```

Vemos que já na primeira iteração o seu código chama a função `exit()`, o que interrompe o programa imediatamente.

Há boa parte do seu código que poderia ser reestruturado, mas vou focar na resposta da sua pergunta aqui: **imprimir valor true quando uma string de tamanho qualquer contém uma letra de outra string**.

O código abaixo realiza essa tarefa com os seguintes passos:

- itera sobre as letras de `s1`;
- para cada letra, pergunta se a letra aparece em `s2` (usando para isso o operador `in`);

  - se for verdade: imprime `True` e termina a iteração usando `break` (não precisamos mais iterar porque já temos a resposta);
  - se não for verdade: tenta com a próxima letra;
- se nenhuma letra de `s1` aparecer dentro de `s2`, então o `break` nunca será executado e o `for` loop irá iterar por todos os caracteres de `s1`. Nesse caso, podemos adicionar um `else` depois do `for` que funciona como um "no-break": SE o `for` loop não quebrar, ENTÃO o que está no `else` executa.
- O `else` corresponde a nenhuma letra de `s1` estar em `s2`, portanto o programa imprime `False`.

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'bca'

for letra in s1:
    if letra in s2:
        print(True)
        break  # "quebra" e sai do for loop
else:  # caso o for loop não tiver sido quebrado ...
    print(False)
```

Se você não está acostumado a usar `else` junto de um `for` loop, outra ideia é transformar isso em uma função que retorna `True`/`False`, e aí imprimir o retorno:

```
def letra_dentro_de(string_busca, string_comparacao):
    for letra in string_busca:
        if letra in string_comparacao:
            return True
    return False


s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'bca'
resultado = letra_dentro_de(s1, s2)
print(resultado)  # output: True
```

Nos dois exemplos, se você trocar `s1` por um string que não inclui nenhuma das letras de `s2` (ex: `s1 = 'def'`), verá que o código imprime `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Está é maneira mais fácil de ser entendida, eu usei o in que seria a mesma coisa de contem também tem a função find()

```
aux = [5, 1, 3, 4, 10]
comparador = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in aux:
    if i in comparador: # verificando se o aux contem no comparador, returna valor e True
        print(i, True)
    else: # senao retorna o valor e False
        print(i, False)
```

Answer (score -2):

Tudo bom Gustavo, não sou um expert em Python mas acho que posso te ajudar.

Primeiro sobre a criacao das listas, não sei se foi pedido do exercicio cria-las com o range de 26, mas não acho que seja uma ideia boa pois desta forma a lista fica "habitada" por número inteiros de 0 a 25 e isto pode te atrapalhar se tu for utilizar a lista para alguma outra tarefa.

```
t = list(range(26))
print(t)
print(type(t[0]))    
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
<class 'int'>
```

Tu pode simplesmente criar a lista declarando uma lista vazia. Se realmente precisar do limite 26 tu pode colocar um break no for controlado pelo len(lista).

Sobre a procura das letras, a forma mais fácil é utilizando o "in", com ele tu pode ver se a letra está dentro da outra string, desta forma.

```
prescricao = ["teste", "banana"]
estoque = ["teste", "parai"]

cont = 0
for palavra in estoque:
    for letra in palavra:
        print(letra)
        if letra in prescricao[cont]:
            print(f"Letra {letra} esta em {prescricao[cont]} -> True")
        else:
            print(f"Letra {letra} nao esta em {prescricao[cont]} -> False")
    cont += 1
```

Esta é apenas uma das formas que se pode resolver este problema, com certeza existem formas mais curtas ou mais simples, está foi apenas a que eu lembrei que poderia te ajudar. Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição. :D